# ngCropper - change aspect ratio on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on ngCropper but i want to dynamically change the aspect ratio on button click like it happens in javascript cropper (https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/)

This is the default option that I have written,

```
vm.options = {
   maximize: true,
   viewMode: 3,
   aspectRatio: 2 / 3,
   crop: function(dataNew) {
        data = dataNew;
   }
};
```

There are 2 button in frontend triggers when 
`ng-click = vm.cropHorizontal()` or `ng-click = vm.cropSquare()`

```
function cropHorizontal() {
     vm.options = {
        aspectRatio: 2 / 3,
        crop: function(dataNew) {
            data = dataNew;
       }
    };
}

function cropSquare() {
   vm.options = {
      aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
      crop: function(dataNew) {
          data = dataNew;
      }
   };
}
```

When I log something in the function I am getting log in the console but not able to change the aspect ratio.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the ngCropper directive and add a watcher on options.aspectRatio like this:

```
    scope.$watch('options.aspectRatio', function (aspectRatio) {
            if (!shown) return;
            element.cropper("setAspectRatio", aspectRatio);
    });
```

This code could go after options.disabled watcher.

In your custom JS, call a function when the aspect ratio checkbox changes:

```
    $scope.updateAspectRatio = function () {
        $scope.options.aspectRatio = $scope.aspectRatio ? 2 / 1 : NaN;        
    }
```